# Can you set a lower limit on a buy limit order or another order type?

Tags: trading, limit-order, smart-order-routing

For example say XYZ is trading at $5 and I want to buy once it reaches $4 but not lower than $3.50. Is their a way to set this up? I wouldn't want to set a limit order at $4 in the chance it gaps below $3.50 and fills me lower than I wanted.

Is their way to do this? I can't seem to figure out the order type on Google or through my broker.

Comment: Why would you _not_ want to buy it at a lower price? Are you thinking if it goes below 3.50 it's a catastrophe that it can't recover from?

Comment: OK That's an unusual scenario (don't buy if it goes below X). Usually traders set a _maximum_ buy price, not a _minimum_, so I don't know of a "Standard" order type that would accomplish that. Maybe if you describe the "trade idea" another solution can be suggested?

Comment: You might be able to achieve that with a Conditional Order.  A Conditional Order  allows  one or more stipulations that must be true before the order can be submitted. The stipulations can be based on price or volume of  XYZ or based on price or volume of tan index. Check with your broker to see if they offer this.

Comment: Thanks Bob. Figured it out. I need to switch brokers and it would be a Conditional order.